# How did wamp server install phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache, wamp

It's very strange because phpmyadmin is not in document root,

but still can visit it by:http://localhost/phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably Aliased to a different location via the httpd.conf file

Something like:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin/ "C:/some/other/location/phpmyadmin/"
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. it's because of the configuration in Apache.